# Deploy MySQL database on Heroku with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, mysql2

I am trying to deploy a Rails project on Heroku. My Rails application uses `mysql2`.

I have tried using the `taps` gem but its not working. I get the following error when I run the command `taps server mysql://root@localhost/heroku_ex tempuser tempass`:

> Failed to connect to database: Sequel::AdapterNotFound -> LoadError: cannot load such file -- mysql

Is there any way to deploy my application on Heroku? I would prefer to only use free add-ons if possible.

Comment: You need to change db to postgres

Comment: @DeepakMahakale, that's not true. Heroku supports PostgreSQL out of the box, but it also supports other databases through add-ons.

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean? Did you get an error message?

Comment: @Chris, I got the error: Failed to connect to database:
  Sequel::AdapterNotFound -> LoadError: cannot load such file -- mysql
when i run the command: taps server mysql://root@localhost/heroku_ex tempuser tempass

Comment: @Harshini, you definitely won't have a MySQL server running on `localhost`, and you won't connect to it as `root`. Are you loading your database connection information from an environment variable, or is it hard-coded?

Comment: @Chris, my db connection is from hard-code.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few moving parts here.

First of all, Heroku doesn't support MySQL by default. If you want to use MySQL instead of PostgreSQL you will have to provision an [add-on that provides it](https://elements.heroku.com/addons). There are currently at least two add-ons that provide MySQL or MariaDB¹ support with a free tier².

Next, Heroku doesn't run database servers on `localhost`. How can you handle different database configurations between your development machine and your Heroku server?

One strategy that is [endorsed by Heroku](https://12factor.net/) is to store configuration in the environment. Following this model lets you alter your application's configuration by modifying environment variables instead of editing files. Luckily, Rails appears to [override `config/database.yml` with configuration from the `DATABASE_URL` variable by default](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database), so this approach should be a good fit.

Very often database add-ons will automatically set an environment variable for you. For example, the [JawsDB Maria add-on sets `JAWSDB_MARIA_URL` when it is provisioned](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/jawsdb-maria#provisioning-the-add-on). This isn't the variable that Rails looks for, so you'll either have to tell Rails to look for `JAWSDB_MARIA_URL` instead of `DATABASE_URL` or manually set `DATABASE_URL` to contain the same URL that JawsDB provides in `JAWSDB_MARIA_URL`.

---

¹MariaDB is a fork of MySQL that aims to be fully-compatible.

²Note that the free tier may be quite limited, e.g. by only providing 5MB of storage. You may have to upgrade to a paid database tier as you continue to develop your application.

Answer (score -2):

I have solved this by adding the pg gem in production and mysql2 in development environment.

```
group :development, :test do
 gem 'mysql2'
end

group :production do
 gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
 gem 'pg'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
 gem 'spring'
 gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
```

Comment: It's a very bad idea to develop (and test!) using one database engine and deploy to a completely different one. You will almost certainly encounter issues in each environment that do not appear in the other. I _strongly_ urge you to either use MySQL on Heroku (as I've described) or switch to PostgreSQL for development and testing.